# Looping code with till user inputs to terminate code

Tags: python, loops

I am making a code to loop with output then ask the user to run it again if they wish

my code is :

```
    import random

    duplicateNumber=0

    def has_duplicates(listToCheck):
        number_set = set(listToCheck)

        if len(number_set) is not len(listToCheck):
            return True
        else:
            return False 

    for i in range(0,1000):
        birthdayList=[]

        for j in range(0,23):  
            birthday=random.randint(1,365)
            birthdayList.append(birthday)

        x = has_duplicates(birthdayList)

        if x==True:
            duplicateNumber+=1

    print ("after 1000 simulations with 23 students there were", duplicateNumber,"simulations with at least one match")


 code with while loop:
import random

duplicateNumber=0

def has_duplicates(listToCheck):
    number_set = set(listToCheck)

    if len(number_set) is not len(listToCheck):
        return True
    else:
        return False 
i=0
while True:
    if i>0:
        prompt = input('Do you wish to continue?')
        if prompt.lower() == 'no':
            break
    birthdayList=[]

    for j in range(0,23):  
        birthday=random.randint(1,365)
        birthdayList.append(birthday)

    x = has_duplicates(birthdayList)

    if x==True:
        duplicateNumber+=1
    i += 1

print ("after ", i," simulations with 23 students there were", duplicateNumber,"simulations with at least one match")
```

I tried adding a while loop but it will just keep asking the question and shows no output. I want my code to show the output, prompts the user if they want to run it again. if they say yes it will show the output again then ask if they want to run it again. this keeps going till the user says no and the program ends, how can I do this?

Comment: can you show where you have tried adding while loop ?

Comment: @MaheshKaria updated questions with while loop

Answer (score 0):

```
import random

duplicateNumber=0

def has_duplicates(listToCheck):
    number_set = set(listToCheck)

    if len(number_set) is not len(listToCheck):
        return True
    else:
        return False 
i=0
while True:
    if i>0:
        prompt = input('Do you wish to continue?')
        if prompt.lower() == 'no':
            break
    birthdayList=[]

    for j in range(0,23):  
        birthday=random.randint(1,365)
        birthdayList.append(birthday)

    x = has_duplicates(birthdayList)

    if x==True:
        duplicateNumber+=1
    i += 1

    print ("after ", i," simulations with 23 students there were", duplicateNumber,"simulations with at least one match")
```

Just move `print()` inside while loop which should fix issue.

Comment: Thank you! is there a way where I can make the simulations start at 1000 and maybe stay at 1000?

Comment: you can make `i = 1000` and comment `i += 1`